# hiding and showing buttons in flex for admin

Tags: apache-flex

I want to show some buttons to the user only if it is an admin. I thought of using state but, I didn't know how to access that buttons in the others mxml page to define their visibility.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, at some point you're application will need to store the information that lets you determine whether the user is an admin or not.

Without knowing anything about your setup; the easiest way is going to be store that value in a static variable somewhere; something like this:

```
public static var isUserAdmin : Boolean = true;
```

Now you can access that property anywhere in the app by referencing the class name.  Static variables exist on a class; not on an instance of a class.

You can use this to control states inside components if that is what you want.  Somewhere in the component, perhaps in an initialize event handler, you can do this:

```
if(myClassWithStaticVaraibles.isUserAdmin){
  currentState = 'adminState';
} else {
  currentState = 'nonAdminState';
}
```

You can also use this to toggle the visibility of buttons or other UI Elements.  This will show a button if the user is an admin:

```
<s:Button visible="{myClassWithStaticVariables.isUserAdmin}" />
```

This will hide a button for user admins:

```
<s:Button visible="{!myClassWithStaticVariables.isUserAdmin}" />
```

There are more complex approaches than using static variables; such as using a framework, such as Swiz or Robotlegs, that support dependency injection of a Singleton like class.  In "real world" applications; use of such frameworks seems to be much more common than the static variable approach.  But, the approach is the same:

1. Store value somewhere
2. Access value in view
3. Modify views display based on the value

Comment: Perfect answer! If I could I would mark it as the solution for this case!